# What is a different representation of this second order ode?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to model in python a second order ode problem, but I don't really get the notation.

Attached are the motion equations.

Are these 2 different ODEs? Is it ${\displaystyle \frac{d^2x}{dy^2}}$?

I know second order ODEs written in the form: ${\displaystyle \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \dots}$

But how should I interpret these two equation? Can it be written in another form? [image: system of ode]

Comment: The dot notation means differentiation with respect to time. $\dot{x} = \frac{dx}{dt}$, $\dot{y} = \frac{dy}{dt}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those equations seem to be a model for the ballistic movement under aerodynamic forces. It can be resumed as

$$
v_x = \dot x\\
v_y = \dot y\\
\dot v_x = k \vert v\vert v_x\\
\dot v_y = -g + k\vert v\vert v_y\\
$$

with $\vert v\vert = \sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}$